# Implementing Authentication for a WebDAV Servlet

Tags: java, webdav

I am currently using [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webdav-servlet/develop) WebDAV Java Servlet Implementation, it's as far as I know the smallest and the easiest to use WebDAV java solution that doesn't depend on Tomcat ( Using WebLogic ).

So I would like to extend this to use my underlying security layer which somewhat uses a database connection to authenticate users.

My question is if this is possible? Does the HttpServletRequest even get the Authentication?

Consider the following method header:

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException { }
```

Now I would like to use req.getPrincipal to get the User Principal containing the Username and Password. However, my getPrincipal always returns null even if I set my WebDAV client to Windows Authentication or anything else for that matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using your own authentication layer, you need to inject your authentication information to the ServletRequest. This is normally done through a filter and wrapped HttpServletRequest.

You can find a good example in CAS,

```
http://www.jasig.org/cas
```

Download the source and look at this class,

```
org.jasig.cas.client.web.filter.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter
```